# Find a point D given points A, B, C so that ABCD is a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Find a point $D(x, y)$ such that the points $A(3, 1)$, $B(4, 0)$, $C(0,3)$ and $D$ are the corners
of a square.

I am aware it is really easy but still have no idea. For example, I see that $|DA|=|DB|$, but how to solve it rigorously?

Comment: HINT: find the mid point of AC and its the same as the mid point of BD so u can find D

Comment: On my screen, I see boxes in front of the $3$'s in points $A$ and $C$.  What symbol, if any, were you trying to produce?

Comment: He does want to produce anything, he wants you to answer his question! ;-).

Comment: See this guide to writing mathematics on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Since $m_{AB}=-1$, $m_{AC}=-\frac{2}{3}$, and $m_{BC}=-\frac{3}{4}$, no two of these 3 sides are perpendicular to each other, so there is not a square with these 3 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

A parallelogram is possible, not a triangle (since AC is obviously not equal to  AB). Here is the graph (assuming you never plotted it yourself).

[image: Graph]

Even for a parallelogram, I think trigonometry is required, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the points onto a graph, then you'll see that you can get from the point A to B by moving one unit right and one unit down. Similarly you can get from point C to point A by moving 3 units right and 2 units down. So to complete the parallelogram you need a point D, which is 1 unit right and 1 unit down from C(i.e. x=1, y=2). You can confirm that this is the correct point, as it takes 3 units to the right and 2 units down to get from D to B, which is the same as getting from C to A.